# Jupyter Notebook fonts antialiasing

Tags: css, fonts, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way to apply the font antialiasing on Jupyter Notebook? I just noticed that the font smoothness of the font around the same size in chrome webpage and Jupyter Notebook are quite different, and it's tiring to stare at such rendered font all the time... [image]